# cookies, sessions , and security

Tags: php, security, cookies

I came up with my own way to protect the moderators on my site. First, I know that a hacker could hijack my session. So what I did was to add a cookie to the moderator and set my algorithm on how to set and unset those cookies.

First, precaution that I took is this when the moderator logs in:

```
        if('Moderator'==is_monitor($name))//function finds who is the user
        {
            ini_set('session.use_only_cookies',true);
            session_start();
            $password_hash = hash('sha256',$salt.hash('sha256', $pass));
            $_SESSION['mod_identify']=$password_hash;
            if(!isset($_Cookie['adderss']))
            {
              setCookie("adderss",$ip_address,time()+60*60*24*365*5,"/");
            }
```

Then I use this to reset the sessions on every page:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
   start_session(); // all sessions should be reset with a new id
}
```

The question is whether setting a cookie for many pages is a burden on the moderator?!?

Do you think that my way is secure enough against session/cookie hijacking?

Comment: As per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php), variable names are case-sensitive. That is, `$_Cookie` is not the same as `$_COOKIE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Use HTTPS - which uses SSL - if you want to prevent session hijacking. Also, never store the *password* of some user's account in the session if that's what `$pass` is.

Alternatively, you could use a Session wrapper class like [this one](http://www.zimuel.it/en/encrypt-php-session-data/). Note that this will **not** protect against session hijacking, rather it simply encrypts the data stored therein.

Also, unless you've created your own custom function named "start_session()", then `session_start()` is the function you want to call to start sessions.

If you want to redirect users to HTTPS, you can do it with apache's mod_rewrite in your .htaccess file like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/admin
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Or something similar, depending on where you want users to be using secure sockets layer.

Comment: lol...that is true. The password gets hashed..so even if someone gets it, it will be useless when trying to login. so using https is the only solution, using 2 cookies isnt more secure?.. thanks for the code, I have one of those classes already..and will use them

Comment: HTTPS is the man. even though it's not a man, it's a machine. kinda like the terminator.  JK. Yeah you're gonna need to use HTTPS if you _really_ want to protect from session hijacking.

Comment: how do I set the session to https, I know that to set a cookie to https you need  to put 1 as the last argument in set_cookie() function

Comment: No, you will have to direct (or redirect) your _visitors_ to `https://domain.com/uri` (for example). This will need to be set in your httpd.conf file or vhost.conf file depending on what you're using.  You can redirect users to HTTPS in your .htaccess file.

Comment: hmm.. what does the hacker get if he hijacks my cookie/session..will he get the name of the session and what is in it?

Comment: yeah pretty much. he/she will get whatever is stored in the cookie that was obtained. for more in-depth info, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking. Watch out for tools like firesheep, etc.  Also, for your own safety you could use some sort of VPN if you want to protect yourself especially in public wifi connections.